# Send message in hindi language using mg91 api in node.js

Tags: node.js, utf-8, sms-gateway, hindi, msg

I am using msg91 Node.js API to send SMS. It is working fine if the message's text is in English.
Now I want to send SMS in Hindi.

Problem is, if I don't encode the message, it returns `Authentication error`.  Post encoding it says the message is sent, but I don't receive any message on the test target.

Error Message:

```
{ success: 'false',
  token: 'Authentication failure' }
```

Sample message is:

> मोजो में आपका स्वागत है

npm module used: msg91

```
npm install --save msg91
```

Comment: Now message is received
    ?????????????????? ????????????

which means that utf-8 encoding error is there while sending and encodeURI thing doesn't work for this.

Comment: Do you mean that you received the message after sometime?

Comment: @prashantsudeep : which function are you using?

Comment: cause for unicode message you are required to use this function :

    //send to single number  
      msg91.sendOnewithUnicode(authkey,number,message,senderid,route,dialcode,function(response){
 
    //Returns Message ID, If Sent Successfully or the appropriate Error Message 
    console.log(response);
 
    });

Comment: how to send sms using msg91 nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Sending SMS via `msg91` is just a simple get call. You don't need to rely on a language specific API.

As long as you send `unicode=1` in the `get` call you can insert hindi text in you messages.

For more information about the same read here - https://control.msg91.com/apidoc/textsms/send-sms.php

Answer (score 1):

You can refer NodeJS package https://www.npmjs.com/package/springedge to send sms. You can install as

```
npm install springedge
```

Code example of sending sms:

```
// send sms 

var springedge = require('springedge');

var params = {
  'apikey': '', // API Key 
  'sender': 'SEDEMO', // Sender Name 
  'to': [
    '919019xxxxxxxx'  //Moblie Number 
  ],
  'message': 'test+message'
};

springedge.messages.send(params, 5000, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(response);
});
```

You will just need api key and trail account to use it. or you can customize it as per your requirement.